# Tipo de atributo para coluna tipo oid do PostgreSQL com EF6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, postgresql, entity-framework-6

Qual o tipo de atributo devo usar para representar uma coluna tipo `oid` do PostgreSQL com Entity Framework 6 Code-First?

Lembrando que o tipo `oid` do PostgreSQL é para armazenar arquivos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como descrito no texto abaixo:

> No support for unsigned integer properties (and confusing error
>   message)

do site referencia [Pagina CodePlex - No support for unsigned integer properties](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1489) , não há suporte para `uint` no *Entity Framework*.

**Qual solução:** utilize `int`

Há [respostas aqui mesmo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29610236), reforçando.

Comment: Desculpe retomar a pergunta, mas surgiram novas dúvidas.
Não entendi como será essa persistência.
Digamos que eu tenha uma classe chamada `Cliente` com três propriedades, `Id`, `Nome`, `Foto`, onde segundo o que foi explicado, `Foto` deve ser do tipo `int`. Supondo nesse caso que a foto foi capturada e está em um diretório temporário.
Meu raciocínio terminou aqui.
Como eu diria ao EF para pegar o arquivo que está no diretório e gravar no banco?
E qual o papel da propriedade `int Foto`?

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva depende da sua regra de negócio, No meu caso eu guardo a foto em um diretório e na base de dados somente o caminho da foto. Dá também para guardar o array de bytes da foto na sua tabela, mas, você vai sobrecarregar o sistema, deixando lento. Para gravar fotos por exemplo em SQLServer tem image ou varbinary(Max) acredito que no postgresql seja bytea  ... Espero ter ajudado ... Se for recomendar gravar o arquivo no disco o acesso é mais rápido ... e mais prático

Comment: Entendo, mas OID também serve para armazenar arquivos no banco, na verdade OID é mais indicado que bytea, tem melhor desempenho e suporta arquivos maiores.
Mas ainda não descobrir como persistir o arquivo com Entity Framework.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva quando eu tenho duvidas eu faço a engenharia reversa eu pego o que tem de tabela no banco e mando gerar as classes para saber qual tipo de dado se encaixa. Tente fazer isso com EntityFramework Reverse Poco CodeFirst Generator https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838/view/Reviews/2 como eu não tenho esse banco instalado e nunca utilizei fica essa duvida particular, peço desculpas

Comment: Como diria alguns amigos meus, "Só que não...".
Infelizmente o suporte ao PostgreSQL no EF ainda é muito limitado. Na busca pela solução acabei descobrindo que EF não permite code-first com PostgreSQL. Sendo assim as tabelas devem ser criadas na mão.
Ai não né, se for para ser assim melhor baixar o nível e meter a mão no ado.net direto.

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva eu sei que no Entity Core isso já foi solucionado, no 6.1.3 tem esses inconvenientes

Answer (score 2):

Segundo a [documentação do provedor Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types.html) (imagino que seja este que esteja usando) o tipo é o `uint`. Como não há suporte no EF a tipos não sinalizados, então use o `int` mesmo. Ou troque de ORM :P